# Swashbuckle generated API document with not well-format JSON in example properties

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

After upgrade Swashbuckle.AspnetCore from version 5.3.0 to 6.1.4, I'm facing with a problem related to `swagger.json` file as screenshot below. There are special characters (BOM - 0xFEFF) in each `example` property. It make the JSON file is not well-formatted.

[image: Special character]

I try to reproduce in other project but it doesn't happen.

**Config Swagger generation**

```cs
     private static void RegisterSwagger(IServiceCollection services, IEnumerable<OpenApiServer> openApiServers)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                foreach (var api in ApiInfo.ApiVersions)
                {
                    options.SwaggerDoc(api.Version, new OpenApiInfo
                    {
                        Title = api.Title,
                        Version = api.Version,
                        Description = api.Description,
                        Contact = api.Contact
                    });
                }

                options.ExampleFilters();
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
                options.DocumentFilter<DocumentFilter>();
                options.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);

                // OAS Rule: oas3-api-servers
                foreach (OpenApiServer server in openApiServers)
                {
                    options.AddServer(server);
                }

                // OAS Rule: operation-operationId
                // Use method name and HTTP method as operationId
                options.CustomOperationIds(apiDesc =>
                {
                    return apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo) ? $"{methodInfo.Name}_{apiDesc.HttpMethod}" : null;
                });

                // OAS Rule: query-strings-camel-case
                options.DescribeAllParametersInCamelCase();
            });
            
            services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblyOf<DataRequestSwaggerExample>();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the root cause.
I use `ExampleFilter` from `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters`. This filter uses `MvcOutputFormatter` to serialize. Currently, I customize `MvcOutputFormatter` for `JSON` format.
After update the Json serializer, the output is well-formatted

https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters/Examples/ExamplesConverter.cs